# Cant get child attributes to save through parent model in rails console ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

So I have been trying to test my models to see if I can add a picture through the rails console using `Gallery.new(:picture => File.new('E:\Owner (Backup)\Pictures\Skateboard 1.jpg', 'r'))` but I get The following error listed below. I am doing this as I cant get a picture to save in my rails application, I just get the re-render of the `new` template and the form  partial listed in the new view.

I was wondering how anyone troubleshoots these errors because from what I can see my models are fine. Also my migrations seem fine also. I figure `accept_nested_attributes_for` allowed the `Picture` model attributes to be passed through the `Gallery` model.

The error in the console is

```
irb(main):002:0> Gallery.new(:picture => File.new('E:\Owner (Backup)\Pictures\Skateboard 1.jpg', 'r'))
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'picture' for Gallery.
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:48:in `_assign_attribute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `_assign_attributes'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `_assign_attributes'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:319:in `initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):003:0> ^C
irb(main):003:0>
```

My models are, Gallery

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :cover, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Picture

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :gallery
  validates :gallery_id, presence: true
  validates :picture, presence: true
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  serialize :picture, JSON
end
```

Migrations, galleries

```
class CreateGalleries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :galleries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :cover

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

pictures

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.integer :gallery_id
      t.string :picture

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'picture' for
>   Gallery.

You are doing it wrong. You should ***associate*** the ***picture*** with ***gallery instance*** instead passing it as an ***attribute to Gallery model***.

```
g = Gallery.new(name: 'Some Name', cover: 'Some Cover')
g.save!
p = g.pictures.new(picture: File.new('E:\Owner (Backup)\Pictures\Skateboard 1.jpg', 'r'))
p.save!
```

Comment: Hi ok right that works now got a bit confused. Do I need to do this in this way in my controller, saving each instance as I cant get it to save using the standard way `@gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)`?

Comment: @LeeEather Not needed. We can use the help of strong params. If you can ask another question regarding, i can help you with that

Comment: Here is question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951335/rails-nested-attributes-not-saving-using-carrierwave) and change `picture` to `pictures` in your answer.