# Rails nested attributes not saving using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I can get the gallery attributes to insert as evident by server log below but picture attributes will not insert as well.

Server response

```
Started POST "/galleries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-13 18:19:23 +1000
Processing by GalleriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LACaMz44B9mn/psLYjzs8qrwo9mr0l2OEIPg+VmCn9CdbGhBh9rDUJ6FE0EOwKCj7aZVjbM4+t0YoaFIRX7IEA==", "gallery"=>{"name"=>"Hello", "cover"=>"123456", "picture"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb943d50 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Lee/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170513-2604-b2lnrz.jpg>, @original_filename="Skateboard 1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[picture][picture]\"; filename=\"Skateboard 1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}, "commit"=>"Create Gallery"}
Unpermitted parameter: picture
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "galleries" ("name", "cover", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Hello"], ["cover", 123456], ["created_at", 2017-05-13 08:19:23 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-13 08:19:23 UTC]]
   (65.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 74ms (ActiveRecord: 66.1ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-13 18:19:23 +1000
....
```

GalleriesController

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
    if @gallery.save       
      flash[:success] = "Picture created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private

    def gallery_params
        params.require(:gallery).permit(:id, :name, :cover, pictures_attributes: [:id, :gallery_id, :picture, :_destroy])
      end
    end
```

_form.html.erb partial rendered from within new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @gallery do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cover %>
    <%= f.text_field :cover %>
  </div>
  <div id="pictures">
    <%= f.fields_for @gallery.pictures do |pic| %>
      <%= pic.file_field :picture %>
  </div>
    <% end %>
  <div id="submit">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Models, Gallery

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :cover, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Picture

```
 class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :gallery
  validates :gallery_id, presence: true
  validates :picture, presence: true
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  serialize :picture, JSON
end
```

Migrations, Gallery

```
class CreateGalleries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :galleries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :cover

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Picture

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.integer :gallery_id
      t.string :picture

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: picture

The error is because your `fields_for` is wrong. The ***first parameter*** of [***`fields_for`***](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) should be a `record_name`(which should be `:pictures` in your case).

> fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)

You are passing `record_object` as a first parameter, which resulting in ***wrong params*** and leading to ***unpermitted error***. Changing your code to below should resolve the issue.

```
<%= f.fields_for :pictures, @gallery.pictures do |pic| %>
  <%= pic.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks pavan for your input. You are right but when I did this the `file_field` for the picture dissapears on the page so I have to do `f.fields_for @gallery.pictures do..` Now I realised to get the parameters permitted I need to name the field as `name: "pictures[picture]"` which gets rid of the error but this only inserts the galleries attributes not the pictures. So to handle this in the controller I need to add `params[:pictures][:picture].each do |pic|` then `@picture = @gallery.pictures.create(picture: pic)` `end` and all works :) Thanks guys

Comment: Sorry actually that produces a error instead it is just `@picture = @gallery.pictures.create(picture: params[:pictures][:picture])` as it is a single picture

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your parameters line here:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LACaMz44B9mn/psLYjzs8qrwo9mr0l2OEIPg+VmCn9CdbGhBh9rDUJ6FE0EOwKCj7aZVjbM4+t0YoaFIRX7IEA==",
"gallery"=>{"name"=>"Hello", "cover"=>"123456", 
"picture"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb943d50 
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Lee/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170513-2604-b2lnrz.jpg>, 
@original_filename="Skateboard 1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[picture][picture]\"; 
filename=\"Skateboard 1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}, "commit"=>"Create Gallery"}
```

and the fact you're getting the result: `Unpermitted parameter: picture`, you should change your strong parameters to

```
def gallery_params
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:id, :name, :cover, picture: [:id, :gallery_id, :picture, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: Yes but I think its saying for picture attributes so the mistake must be somewhere else?

Comment: @LeeEather You're currently allowing the parameter hash `pictures_attributes`, but you're submitting the parameter hash `picture`.

Comment: I tried that and I get a `unknown attribute error picture for Gallery` I am pretty sure you have to specify the attributes you have for pictures as `picture_attributes` for the parameters from the form even just adding the `Picture` model attributes without specifically referencing them still doesn't work also so must be something else